# HTML List Styling with Links

Tags: css, less, html-lists

I have a menu that consists of an unordered list styled to look like a grid, the grid box changes color when the mouse hovers over it. Plain and simple. My problem is when I add a link to the text inside the `li` the hover basically breaks. (See the Fiddle below for reference and how hover is different between the link and non-link `li`)

I need to style the link to look the same way as the un-styled text when hovering over the grid, not just the actual link and make the entire grid box area clickable.

I've been messing with it for a while but can't get it to work the way I want it.

```
<style>
.admin-panel {
    overflow: hidden;

    li {
        float: left;
        width: 33%;
        height: 115px;
        padding: 10px;
        line-height: 1.4;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
    }

    li:hover, li a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #778ba1;
    }

    .glyphicon {
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .admin-panel-class {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
}
</style>

<div class="admin-panel">
    <ul class="admin-panel-list">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
                <span class="admin-panel-class">My Workshops</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            <span class="admin-panel-class">Create Workshop</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
            <span class="admin-panel-class">Edit Workshop</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
            <span class="admin-panel-class">Resource Allocation</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            <span class="admin-panel-class">Reservation Approval</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            <span class="admin-panel-class">Facilities Reservation Approval</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            <span class="admin-panel-class">Room Calendars</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span>
            <span class="admin-panel-class">Global Reports</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>
            <span class="admin-panel-class">Sing-In Tablets</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
            <span class="admin-panel-class">Menu Editor</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            <span class="admin-panel-class">Edit Users</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15109/)

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15128/) what you need?

Comment: The hover in your example works good thanks, now the only thing is to make the entire grid box area clickable instead of only the text clickable

Comment: But your `li` has a padding of 10px. Is it ok if the space other than those 10px alone is clickable? Else, we may have to use absolute positioning.

Comment: Finally got it to work. New Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15130/ Your comment was helpful, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All anchor (`a`) tags have default styling when it comes to text colors (unlike `span` tags which inherit the color from their parent).  In the code provided in question, you were applying the `color` to the `li` element when it is hovered and to the `a` element only when the `a` itself is hovered.

```
li:hover, li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #778ba1;
}
```

Instead of the above, apply the `color` to the `a` element also when the `li` is hovered on. This would fix the hover text color problem.

```
li:hover, li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #778ba1;
}
```

---

For making the entire grid box area as clickable, you would need to set the `display` property of the anchor as either `block` or `inline-block` and give it 100% width and height of the parent. Note that this would still leave the `padding` area of the grid as unclickable.

```
.admin-panel-list li a{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

If you need the padding area also to be clickable then remove the padding from the `li` and add it to the `a` instead (like given below):

```
.admin-panel-list li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, just before you posted this I got it to work exactly the same way you are showing here :) https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15130/